# Web App (Svelte): How to divide screen in distinct sections

Tags: html, css, svelte

I am creating a program calculating flow in piping systems. In the user interface, the program contains a graphical drawing diagram, a ribbon on top of the screen containing functions helping the user drawing, and possibly a side ribbon with additional functions.

Here i've included a picture explaining my intentions:

[image: Image explaining my intentions.]

As of now, my approach to achieve the division of screen, is to have nested elements in a tree structure, where the main branches are the divisions of the screen (the functional areas and the graphical drawing area). In the graphical area, the objects drawn in this area are positioned using absolute coordinates w.r.t. the drawing area element, and are also nested inside this element. As of now, this is the progress that has been made (grey area is the graphical drawing area, the red area is going to contain functions):

[image: The current progress.]

To obtain this current division of screen, the general html code looks like this, and the general css code uses mainly certain flex-settings.

App.svelte:

```
<main class="h-screen w-screen">
  
  <section class="screen">

    <!-- Creates a main bar. Will contain several functions and options. -->
    <Bar/>
  
    <!-- Creates the drawing board. -->
    <DrawBoard/>

  </section>

</main>
```

DrawBoard.svelte:

```
<section class='board' on:mouseup|self={$selected != null ? createObject : null}>

    <!-- Displays all objects contained in the MainDataStructure. -->
    {#each $editor.objects as object}
        <ObjectOnBoard bind:object={object}/>
    {/each}

    <ObjectSelection/>

</section>
```

Using this method leads to several problems. As can be seen in the current progress, one object is moved to the edge of the screen, but instead of going out of the screen, it appears above the functional area. I would want to elements inside elements (the object inside the graphical area) disappear if they went out of the element, as if the graphical area was a screen of its own just like the whole tab. This leads me to my question:

Is this the right approach to achieve the user interface with area divisions i want? It seems so easy to not include a certain combination of setting in css, and then the different sections of the screen will intersect each other. I want to imagine that one solution would be to create one html body for each area, so that elements of each area would never intersect each other (i know that a document only has one body). Is there a totally different approach than the one shown, or do i have to find just the right (imo. [kludgy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kludge)) css settings, so that i make the visuals work as intented? And if this is the right approach, what kind of css-settings and other settings should i look into?

Comment: Please do *not* screenshot code. You can insert it as text and use the "code" button to have it formatted as such.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder, image is replaced by code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) for the main layout. (Though this can be done with two flex layouts as well.) You can, for example, use [`grid-template-areas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas) to set up named areas and then position element in them.

Elements intersecting other areas is just an issue of [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow). Either let the individual sections overflow with scroll (`auto`/`scroll`) or cut off their contents (`hidden`).

Comment: Thank you, that solved all current problems! So this is propably the right approach anyways? It's hard to know when you're new to html and css and have never tried all these things.

Comment: Well, I would wrap the section components in another elements and use that for layout. That way the section components do not have to "know" about their surroundings. [Example](https://svelte.dev/repl/92cc2951d6e84172a83eeb14e88941ae?version=3.49.0)

Comment: That's an amazing example, i'll 100% be incorporating that layout technique. Without googling anything, is it easy to make the lines in the grid draggable?

Comment: There is no native method to my knowledge, unfortunately. There are JS libraries for that, which will insert an additional element that e.g. adjusts the relation of the adjacent columns/rows. I have used [`split-grid`](https://github.com/nathancahill/split/tree/master/packages/split-grid) for this before.

Comment: [Example with splitters](https://svelte.dev/repl/e8e97cf1fe694ed7ad13d55118e4e0ec?version=3.49.0)

Comment: This https://github.com/orefalo/svelte-splitpanes would be a Svelte library for splitters

Comment: Thank you guys alot, this is everything i need regarding this topic!